# Drop shadow for a line in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, view, dropshadow

I want to implement a drop shadow for a line something like this:

[image]

What I did so far:

```
<View style=
  {{
    elevation: 5,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    bottom: 1,
  }}
>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Svg, { LinearGradient, Defs, Stop, Rect } from 'react-native-svg'

<Svg height="100" width="100%" style={{ zIndex: 1, marginTop: -50 }}>
    <Defs>
        <LinearGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
            <Stop offset="0" stopColor="#e6e6e6" stopOpacity="1" />
            <Stop offset="1" stopColor="#e6e6e6" stopOpacity="0.01" />
        </LinearGradient>
    </Defs>
    <Rect height="100" width="100%" fill="url(#grad)" />
</Svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code this might help you, Your can change the color as your theme.

```
cardContainer: {
 borderBottomWidth: 1,
 borderColor: #4d4d4d,
 shadowColor: #4d4d4d,
 shadowOffset: {
  width: 0,
  height: 8,
 },
 shadowOpacity: 0.8,
 shadowRadius: 13.51,
 elevation: 5,
}
```

Comment: Didn't helped! this is creating shadow all around. I just want shadow beneath an invisible line.

Comment: I have change `borderBottomWidth` just `borderBottomWidth` you can test now this will work for you.

Comment: Which component should I apply these style to? A button or a view or anything else?

Comment: You can copy these apply and apply to `<View>` `<Button>` or any component.

Comment: Didn't worked! Did you check this code on your machine?  You can share the snack expo link as well.